# Need to display data in GridView below after Selection of 2 DropDowns on their Button Click without using database in real time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, binding, dropdownlistfor

Please help to Display Data which we are selecting in DropDownList will Fill in the GridView Row Instantly.

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Menu2.aspx.cs" Inherits="MasalaStore.Menu2" %>

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- General meta information -->
    <title>Menu</title>
    <%--    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />--%>
    <!-- // General meta information -->


    <!-- Load Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.query-2.1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/rainbows.js"></script>
    <!-- // Load Javascipt -->

    <!-- Load stylesheets -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
    <%--  <style>
    input[type='text']::placeholder
    {   
        text-align: center;      /* for Chrome, Firefox, Opera */
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder
    { 
        text-align: center;      /* for IE 10-11 */
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder
    { 
        text-align: center;      /* for IE Edge */
    }
</style>--%>
    <!-- // Load stylesheets -->
    <style>
        .mydropdownlist {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #cc2a41;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .mydropdownlist1 {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px 12px;
            background-color: #292929;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
   
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" WatermarkText="Select a car" Width="300%" Height="30px" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_onSelectIndexChanged">
                        <Items>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Haldi" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Jeera" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Amchoor" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Ajwain" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Dhaniya" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Kasturi Methi" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Mirch Pisi" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Mirch Kuti" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Kashmiri Mirch" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Mirch Pili" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Garam Masala" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Chana Masala" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Kitchen Kind" Value="13"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Dal Masala" Value="14"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Chat Masala" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Sambhar Masala" Value="16"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Chhole Masala" Value="17"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Shahi Paneer Masala" Value="18"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Black Salt" Value="19"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Sendha Salt" Value="20"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Sonth Pisi" Value="21"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Tej Patta" Value="22"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Loung" Value="23"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Kali Mirch Sabut" Value="24"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Kali Mirch Pisi" Value="25"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Kalonji" Value="26"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Elaichi Badi" Value="27"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Elaichi Chhoti" Value="28"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Hing" Value="29"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Dalchini" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Javitri" Value="31"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Jaifal" Value="32"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Postdana" Value="33"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Ajinomoto" Value="34"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Safed Mirch" Value="35"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Imli" Value="36"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Methi Dana" Value="37"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Raee" Value="38"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Saunf" Value="39"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Besan" Value="40"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Jeera Pisa" Value="41"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pasta" Value="42"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Tarbuj ke Beej" Value="43"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Sabut Lal Mirch" Value="44"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Sabut Dhaniya" Value="45"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Moong Dal Mangodi" Value="46"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Sabudana" Value="47"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Supari" Value="48"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Star Flower" Value="49"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Til" Value="50"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Shahi Jeera" Value="51"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Anardana" Value="52"></asp:ListItem>
                        </Items>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; margin-left:350px;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" WatermarkText="Select a car" Width="300%" Height="30px" EnableViewState="true">
                        <Items>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="10g" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="20g" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="50g" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="100g" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="200g" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="300g" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="400g" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="500g" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="600g" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="700g" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="800g" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="900g" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="1kg" Value="13"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2kg" Value="14"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="3kg" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="4kg" Value="16"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="5kg" Value="17"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="10kg" Value="18"></asp:ListItem>
                        </Items>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; margin-left:300px;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Width="200%" Height="40px" Text="Submit" BackColor="BlanchedAlmond" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click">
                    </asp:Button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                 <asp:Panel ID="pnlGrid" CssClass="panel" runat="server" CellPadding="20" CellSpacing="25">
            <div style="text-align: center">

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="gridview" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" GridLines="Vertical">
                    <Columns>
                        <%--<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Height="40px" HeaderText="Masala Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Prize" />--%>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.NO."><ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridViewAltRow" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridViewSelectedRow" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="gridViewPager" />
                </asp:GridView>

            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

CODE BEHIND : In this i tried a simple code to bind Dropdown data so then First Row has come after submitting the selection of Dropdowns but after that if i want another selection from dropdowns and submitting then it is not taking another Row.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MasalaStore
{
    public partial class Menu2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString());
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            //if (DropDownList1.Text != null && DropDownList2.Text != null)
            //{

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt.Columns.Add("S.No.", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add("ITEM", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("QUANTITY", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PRIZE", typeof(string));

            DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();    // Create New Row and Bind Data to Columns
            dtrow["Item"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
            dtrow["Quantity"] = DropDownList2.SelectedItem;
            dtrow["Prize"] = "#";
            dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

            //if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            //{
                GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                GridView2.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
                DropDownList2.ClearSelection();
            //}
        }

        protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.BindGrid();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.Cells[1].Text).ToUpper() == "OUT OF STOCK")
                {
                    // CHANGE THE COLOR OF THE CELL.
                    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;
                    e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void ddl_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

[image: Image for a rough Idea]

Comment: So do you want the two drop boxes values to be added to the grid when you select the drop downs? Do you want this to occur when you selected the 2nd drop down? And if you change the 2nd dropdown, then the two drops are added to the grid again? So what is not clear here is do you select both drops, hit a button to add to the grid, or can one select either drop and then the values go? You not defined WHEN and at what point the drop selecting is to add to the grid row. So perhaps 2nd drop? And then after selecting 2nd drop, do we clear the two dropdowns? And user can't delete from grid?

Comment: Yes i want to select both dropdown values 1 by 1 and when i hit submit button just it will add as a row in gridview, first row i already submitted but after i select dropdowns second time it wil not adding 2nd row, it is changing values in first row only.

Comment: Actually first you will select Item from 1st Dropdown and then you will select Quantity from 2nd Dropdown and then you will press Submit Button after that both values wil show in GridView as you can see already 1st Row is showing in Photo in GridView. 
Please check.

Comment: Ok, then as noted - see the code below - it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then we can use this code:

Hitting submit will add the row, clear the two drop downs.

The code will look like this:

NOTE VERY close how we declared the MyTable at the forms class level.

```
private DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();

public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        SetUpGrid();
        ViewState["MyTable"] = MyTable;
    }
    else
        MyTable = ViewState["MyTable"];
}


public void SetUpGrid()
{
    MyTable.Columns.Add("ITEM", typeof(string));
    MyTable.Columns.Add("QUANTITY", typeof(Int32));
    MyTable.Columns.Add("PRIZE", typeof(Int32));
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // add row to table

    DataRow OneRow = MyTable.Rows.Add;

    OneRow("ITEM") = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    OneRow("QUANTITY") = 1;
    OneRow("PRIZE") = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

    GridView2.DataSource = MyTable;
    GridView2.DataBind();

    DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
    DropDownList2.ClearSelection();
}
}
```

so the trick here is on first page load:

Setup the table.

But, we have to SAVE the state of this table. This makes it all easy to add a row. And each time we add a new row, we re-bind grid, clear the dropdowns.

Comment: Yes, Its Working Sir.